# Error importing Leaflet and Leaflet-Providers when run in node

Tags: node.js, leaflet, es6-modules

I am running unit tests on a leaflet app with tape + babel-register using es6 modules and I'm getting

```
ReferenceError: L is not defined
```

in leaflet-providers.js when importing leaflet and leaflet-providers in the module I am testing.

testfile.js

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import { provider } from 'leaflet-providers';
```

I'm not entirely sure my syntax is correct for importing a leaflet plugin using es6 modules, but it's working for me in the browser, and only not working when I run unit tests through node.

Why is leaflet-providers unable to find L when run through node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser Leaflet attaches to the `window` object, Node doesn't have that. In addition, since everything is a module, scope is restricted to the file level. Node does have a `global` object though that is a pseudo equivalent to `window`, with some differences.

You'll probably also need something like jsdom to provide a window object for leaflet-providers to interact with.

I use Mocha, but the following gives me no errors and attaches the providers function to `L.tileLayer.providers`:

### script

```
"mocha": "mocha ./test/index.js -r jsdom-global/register
```

### index.js

```
 global.L = require('leaflet');
 require('leaflet-providers');
```

My jsdom packages are `jsdom` and `jsdom-global`